# Change subdomain URL without moving files

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I cannot solve a problem, I need to 'move' the subdomain URL `subdomain.mywebsite.com` in the URL `mywebsite.com/subdomain`.
The subdomain is in a separated db.

What I did:

- Changed the WordPress Site URLs Using wp-config.php Changed WordPress
- Site URLs in the Database Using phpMyAdmin
- Saved the Wordpress permalinks
- Created a folder called 'subdomain' under 'mywebsite' root
- Copied and modified the index.php in the 'subdomain' folder under 'mywebsite' root

  /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
  require( dirname( **FILE** ) . '/subdomain/wp-blog-header.php' );

Results: the URL is changed but I've got a blank page.

Anyone know if I made some mistake?

Comment: “Blank page” likely means that you should go and enable proper PHP error reporting first of all, resp. check the error log.

Comment: You are “in” `subdomain/index.php`, so `dirname( __FILE__ )` will return `subdomain` – to which you append `/subdomain/wp-blog-header.php`, so require will be looking for a file `subdomain/subdomain/wp-blog-header.php` now. I’m guessing that doesn’t actually exist …?

Comment: Thank's I have found this  AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace. Now I'm checking my htaccess `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /subdomain/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdomain/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
`

Comment: @CBroe `subdomain/subdomain/wp-blog-header.php` doesn't exist. I really don't understand if `/subdomain/wp-blog-header.php` is related to the 'main' folder or the new 'subdomain' folder in the root. I don't understand what I have to write there.

Comment: I think we need more details about your setup first of all here. _“The subdomain is in a separated db”_ - does that mean we are talking about a WP multisite, so it is using the same file base? Or a completely separate WP installation? If the latter, then I don’t think copying just a single file into the subdomain folder makes much sense to begin with, I’d expect you’ll run into further problems with paths for assets/uploaded files.

Comment: ..A separate WP installation. I did not know because in the guides that I have read no one specify what you said. What do you suggest to do?

Comment: I would move the complete WP installation for that second site into the subdomain folder. And then you will have to modify the .htaccess of the main system, so that it lets all requests for `/subdomain/` and paths below that pass through unmodified.

Comment: I wanted to avoid moving everything but I got it. I follow your advice. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with the debug true in wp-config.php?

Comment: Just now and I've got  _function() is deprecated in /srv/www/w......plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 258

Comment: nothing change, blank page. I suspect of  'the require( dirname( FILE ) . '/subdomain/wp-blog-header.php' );'

Comment: I'll call my hosting tomorrow.